# Problem with two dimensional collision

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, collision

I'm having it hard trying to solve this problem, i've tried but still with no certain results. The problem is this, We have an object with a triangular rectangular shape, above this object there is a ball, they are in deep space (no other force is present). The object goes up and hits the ball. Their centers are are perfectly aligned in vertical. The trajectory of the object is straight vertical forming 90 º between the X-axis and Y-axis. The coeficient of restitution is 0.9 (more details in the image) Question: What will be the exit angle with respect to the X-axis, the ball will have after the collision?

EDIT: It's not homework!! i clearly wrote that i can't solve this problem, and it is just a problem that i myself formulated, and i'm trying to understand the physics behind the two dimensional collisions. This site appears to be about physics, so the question is not out of physics topics.

[image]

Object shape:

[image]

Comment: Hi Mr98. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\vec p = \sum \vec p_i = const. $

---

Ok, assuming:

- this really is no homework
- you know that r, v, p and M all are vector quantities
- $E_{kin}$ is a scalar from a scalar product $\sum \frac{1}{m_i} \vec p \vec p$
- you are familiar with the 3 conservation laws relevant here
- you know how to decode compact information used in physics, the *cosmos of a formula*.

That's *lazyness* on a very high level of providing information $\dots$

### 1. Flaws in your drawing

Knowing it's just a sketch it's imprecise w.r.t. center of masses. It's more like this; more flaws below:

[image: centers]

### 2. Initial situation

So **before** collision we have it like this, where I depicted both vectors for momentum AND for angular momentum, which will come into play in a minute:

[image: initial]

### 3. Contact

You see, the contact point is shifted to the left, off-centers. For further calculation you need to calculate, where it is $\vec r_{contact}$.

Momentum $\vec p$ will decompose as sketched to the right into:

- a component towards the ball center (red)
- a tangential component (pink)

Which introduces vector $\vec M$ for angular momentum. It was there all the time, being zero, and now it becomes $\vec M = \vec M_1 + \vec M_2 = 0$.

As depicted to the right, all 3 conservation laws must still hold. Continue from there. I suggest a 2-step process:

1. first assuming NO friction, i.e. calculate the ideal case as a reference
2. repeat with friction, introducing necessary changes, like Energy-loss (you may want to apply the Lagrange or Hamilton approach on this).

Further complications may arise from the fact that both bodies have to separate fast enough. If they don't, the ball will rotate clockwise, the rotating triangle counterclockwise AND perhaps will hit the ball at least one more time. Which raises the question: when, under which conditions? Good to know from an engineering point of view.

[image: contact]

### Summary

Some flaws and missing information were in the question.

All has been said with the simple conservation law on momentum, which often is forgotten. Applying it automatically leads to relevant questions, as shown here.

The route towards results was laid out in more detail.

Comment: Please delete this answer so i can delete my question, because according to this site my question is off topic. Also your answer is useless.

Comment: Deletion is up to the admins. My hint is perfect. Bye

Comment: Your answer is useless, you don't explain nothing. Next time if you are lazy to explain, don't even answer no question.